# Java 8 stream operation on empty list

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am just wondering what will be behavior of Java 8 *stream* on empty list.

```
List<?> emptyList = new ArrayList<>();
List<?> processedList = emptyList.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Will this be empty list or `null`?

I know *streams* do lazy propagation, so in this case will call go to `collect()` method or just it will end at `stream()` method?

Comment: well for a different point all together, using raw types this wouldn't compile even.. just that you could have given it a try as well.

Comment: Yeah actually I meant to ask for a specific data type. But that's a interesting information you provided here. These days so much dependent on IDE for these kind of stuffs.

Comment: why -1 for this :/

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`collect` is a terminal operation, so it must be evaluated.

When terminating a `Stream` pipeline with `collect(Collectors.toList())`, you'll always get an output `List` (you'll never get `null`). If the `Stream` is empty (and it doesn't matter if it's empty due to the source of the stream being empty, or due to all the elements of the stream being filtered out prior to the terminal operation), the output `List` will be empty too.

Answer (score 8):

You will get a empty collection.
As **collect** is explained in [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html):

> Performs a mutable reduction operation on the elements of this stream using a Collector.

and the **mutable reduction**:

> A mutable reduction operation accumulates input elements into a mutable result container, such as a Collection or StringBuilder, as it processes the elements in the stream.

You will get a empty collection because of the origin input is empty or due to the filter operation.

Thanks for @Andy Turner 's tips.

> It's the fact that toList() accumulates into a new list that means it doesn't return null.

And the doc gets explain for the Collectors.toList() with this:

> Returns a Collector that accumulates the input elements into a new List.

We can get from the source code

```java
    public static <T>
    Collector<T, ?, List<T>> toList() {
        return new CollectorImpl<>((Supplier<List<T>>) ArrayList::new, List::add,
                                   (left, right) -> { left.addAll(right); return left; },
                                   CH_ID);
    }
```

that it will never make a null output but you can still get a null with customized Collector as Andy shows.

Comment: Whilst what you have said here is true, nothing precludes a collector yielding null. For example, `.collect(Collector.of(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add, (a, b) -> a, a -> null))` (or something like) [would yield null](https://ideone.com/Lx4wDR). It's the fact that `toList()` accumulates into a new list that means it doesn't return null.

Comment: @AndyTurner You are right with a better explain to the collect mechanism.

Comment: dont say `Collectors.toList()` but try to be more general and say `.collect()`